# Symfony2.8. How to get data from post request

Tags: php, json, symfony, post, save

How can I receive data from POST request in my controller?
I don't use twig.

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
   //when I use
   $content = $request->getContent();
   // as result I see "string" with need field and value. It's not json
   // array
   // value like
   /* 
      string '------WebKitFormBoundaryI12ukQBs3HdmPjvh
      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

      "valuefortitle"
      ------WebKitFormBoundaryI12ukQBs3HdmPjvh
      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

      "supername"
      ------WebKitFormBoundaryI12ukQBs3HdmPjvh--
      ' (length=253)
      */
}
```

Or how can I serialize(convert) Post data to object or array

I send request using Postman with header "Content-Type: application/json".

And can you show me how to save file(image)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use for **POST** request :

```
$request->request->get('data');
```

For **GET** request:

```
$request->query->get('data');
```

For **FILE** queries:

```
$request->files.
```

And ask your questions `How to save image?`, you must create `uploads -> excels`:

```
$dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/uploads/images/';
$name = uniqid() . '.jpeg';

foreach ($request->files as $uploadedFile) {
    $uploadedFile->move($dir, $name);
}
$file = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . "/../web/uploads/images/" . $name;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    echo "Successfully saved";
}
```

Comment: As result I see "null".

Comment: can you answer my question as well Imanali I am facing similar problem here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44352796/1395965

Answer (score 1):

Dump all data from request to find possible problem with: `$request->request->all();`

Answer (score 0):

`$request->request->get('content');`

POST: `$request->request->get('<propertyName>');`

GET: `$request->query->get('<propertyName>');`