# I want to pass array of IDs to route in Symfony

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, symfony-3.3

this is my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/order", name="finish")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(OrderType::class);

    // get data using the ids pass to the request...
    // handle the form and redirect to homepage

    return $this->render(
        "orders/order_view.html.twig",
       ['order'=>$form->createView()]
    );

}
```

I would like to pass some IDs to the request so i can get the needed data with doctrine.
After that handle the form create new order and add to it the products that i already have thanks to the ids passed.

i  tried passing the ids using ajax on button click:

```
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/order',
            data: {'arr':[2,3,4]} // sample ids
        }
    ).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("some error")
    })
```

but it just returns the HTML. What i need is to render the form in the specified route ("/order")  so i can handle it and insert into the database the new order with products added to it

Comment: I think you can get you ajax data using $request->getContent()

Answer (score 0):

I here answered to like this question:

[Symfony2.8. How to get data from post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386182/symfony2-8-how-to-get-data-from-post-request/35386268#35386268)

You can use for POST request :

```
$request->request->get('data');
```

For GET request:

```
$request->query->get('data');
```

For FILE queries:

```
$request->files.
```

Comment: What i need to know is how to pass the data to the request